# Ajuda para alterar variáveis das SESSION

Tags: php

Estou precisando alterar os valores das SESSION's nome, login e senha, mas não estou conseguindo.

Acho eu que o problema esta nesta parte do código,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ // Se a Session não for iniciada
$nome = 'Nome do Usuário'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
$login = 'usuario'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
$senha = '123'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

}else{

if(isset($_SESSION)){ // Se a Session for iniciada
```

pois quando eu a retiro, consigo pelo menos grava as alterações nas SESSION's, usando o WAMPSERVER.

Abaixo posto o código que estou usando junto com o endereço http://buziosnegocios.com.br/ de acesso para que os amigos possam verificar o que esta acontecendo, ou seja, o que não esta acontecendo ;).

Código:

```
<?php
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ // Se a Session não for iniciada
$nome = 'Nome do Usuário'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
$login = 'usuario'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
$senha = '123'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

}else{

if(isset($_SESSION)){ // Se a Session for iniciada
$nome = $_SESSION["nome"];
if($nome) {
$login = $_SESSION["login"];
if($login) {
$senha = $_SESSION["senha"];
if($senha) {
}}}}}
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<label>Nome do Usuário: </label><span><?php echo $nome ?></span><br /><br />
<label>Login do Usuário: </label><span><?php echo $login ?></span><br /><br />
<label>Senha do Usuário: </label><span><?php echo $senha ?></span><br /><br />

<form method="post">    
<label>Nome do Usuário:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>"><br /><br />
<label>Login do Usuário:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo $login ?>"><br /><br />
<label>Senha do Usuário:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="senha" value="<?php echo $senha ?>"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar" />
</form>

<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
if($nome) {
$_SESSION["nome"] = $nome ;

$login = $_POST["login"];
if($login) {
$_SESSION["login"] = $login ;

$senha = $_POST["senha"];
if($senha) {
$_SESSION["senha"] = $senha ;

header('Location:index.php');
}}}
?>
```

No aguardo de boas dicas, e agradeço à todos pela atenção.
Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom se eu fosse fazer, que  no caso deve ser o que voce quer fazer eu faria assim.

```
 <?php 
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.

         if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ 
      // Se a Session não existir eu crio...
        $nome = 'Nome do Usuário'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
        $login = 'usuario'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
        $senha = '123'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

    //Armazena os dados na sessão que pode ser bidimensiona(array)
         $_SESSION['usuario']['nome']=$nome;
        $_SESSION['usuario']['login']=$login;
        $_SESSION['usuario']['senha']=$senha;

        }else if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
         // Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
        $nome = $_SESSION['usuario']["nome"];
        $login = $_SESSION['usuario']["login"];
        $senha = $_SESSION['usuario']["senha"];
    }
        ?>
```

Ai ali na parte de baixo do código, no envio do form, seria recomendado voce fazer assim.
Primeiro mudar o botão, colocando o name dele

```
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar" name="atualizar"/>
```

Ai no php...

```
      <?php 
    //pega o valor do botao
    $botao=$_POST['atualizar'];
    //verifica se o botao foi clicado
    if($botao=="Atualizar"){
       $nome = $_POST["nome"];
       $login = $_POST["login"];
       $senha = $_POST["senha"];
            if(!empty($nome) && !empty($login) && !empty($senha)) {
            $_SESSION['usuario']["nome"] = $nome ;
            $_SESSION['usuario']["login"] = $login ;
            $_SESSION['usuario']["senha"] = $senha ;

            header('Location:index.php');
            }}
        ?>
```

Acho que se compreendi direito o seu problema, isso irá resolver. Porque ali no sue codigo voce pega o nome de uma sessão onde não sei onde voce criou, que no caso não existe, pois ela seria a sessão usuario e nao nome, senha...
Caso, eu nao tenha compreendido direito a sua situação comenta ai para eu te ajudar melhor. Não mexi nesses IFs ai no final, mas da para dar uma melhorada...

Atualização: Faria assim com esses IFs..., em vez dos 3, faria tudo em uma tacada só. E caso nunca tenha usado, essa função empty(), ela verifica se a variável esta vazia, que no caso eu neguei ela usando !empty(), ou seja, se ela nao for vazia, ai ele vai fazer, ai já verifiquei as 3 juntas, porque acredito que você queira atualizar somente quando os 3 nao forem vazias...
E sobre o textarea, acredito que seria a mesma logica. E sobre ser iniciante em PHP, o começo é assim mesmo, quando vê você já vai estar fazendo tudo e corrigindo os erros que forem surgindo... Abraço, qualquer duvida comenta ai.

Comment: Olá LocalHost, funcionou liso liso, muito obrigado pela sua orientação. Mas te faço uma pergunta, posso usar esse mesmo raciocínio para quando eu for usar um textarea. E como posso melhorar esses IFs, me da uma dica ai pois como você já deve ter visto, sou muito leigo em PHP, **;)**. Estou aprendendo PHP usando tutoriais pegos no YouTube, e tento aplicar para aprender um pouco a cada tutorial. Mande sua ideia para melhorar os IFs, valeu? Grande abraço, e mais uma vez **BRIGADÃO**...

Comment: Editei os IFs no final ali, dá uma olhada...

Comment: Ola LocalHost, estou tentando usar a mesma logica para usar com botões radio, mas não estou conseguindo. Tem como você me dar mas essa auda, e me mostrar onde estou errando, ou a logicaserá diferente se tratando de botões radio?

O Código que estou usando é o Abaixo:

Comment: estarei postando o código respondendo a minha própria pergunta, valeu?

Answer (score 0):

Estou editando e respondendo a minha própria pergunta com o código funcionando.

```
<?php 
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.
if(!isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){ 
// Se a Session não existir eu crio...
$face_status = 'Sim'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

//Armazena os dados na sessão que pode ser bidimensiona(array)
$_SESSION['rede_sociais']['face_status']=$face_status;

}else if(isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){

// Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
    $face_status = $_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"];
}

<?php
//pega o valor do botao
$botao=$_POST['face'];
//verifica se o botao foi clicado
if($botao=="Atualizar"){
$face_status = $_POST["face_status"];
if(!empty($face_status)) {
$_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"] = $face_status ;

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cabe_rede_sociais.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
</script>";

}}
?>

<form method="post">
<label>Habilitar o Link do FaceBook?</label><br><br>
<input type='radio' name='face_status' value='Sim' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
<input type="radio" name="face_status" value='Não'><label>Não</label>
<input type="submit" name="face" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

Espero que ajude a outros amigos com o mesmo problema de gravar na SESSION usando botões (Tag) radio.

Grande abraço à todos.

Comment: Opa e ai, creio que esta tudo certinho, exceto pela abertura ta tag <?php no meio do código, ali antes do
 //pega o valor do botao
$botao=$_POST['face'];
E ali onde você usou js para redirecionar... Se você usou só para redirecionar recomendo usar  em php assim header("location:cabe_rede_sociais.php");
Porque ai ele já redireciona direto do php, porque desa forma o php manda para o navegador o código js, e depois de processado ele redireciona, com o php já faz direto, percebe-se uma diferença de delay maior quando se usa servidor nao local.
Acho que é isso, qualquer coisa comenta ai.

Comment: Olá LocalHost, beleza? Eu segui seu conselho e já corrigi as falhas no código acima, valeu mesmo!!! Mas se possível de uma olhada neste POST (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131598/ajuda-com-tag-radio-para-gravar-em-session), e me ajude a solucionar o problema que nele menciono. Grande Abraço.

Comment: @MuriloCabral você respondeu a pergunta que você linkou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131598/3117 ela não responde a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado com a ajuda do amigo Miguel, conforme [POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131834/duvida-em-cadastrar-dados-com-bot%C3%B5es-radio/131908#131908)

Abaixo código funcionando:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])) {

if(isset($_POST['status_prod']) && ($_POST['status_prod']) == 0) { // Desabilita o Botão.
    $link_prod = null;
    $status_prod = 'Não';
}else{
    $_POST['status_prod'] == 1; // Habilita o Botão com o Link de destino.
        $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
        $status_prod = 'Sim';
        }
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod'] = $status_prod;
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod'] = $link_prod;

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
        <script language='javascript'>
        window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
        </script>";
        }
?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'/><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Abraços à todos.