# Ajuda com tag radio para gravar em $_SESSION

Tags: php

Olá, usando o código abaixo (EDITADO) para gravar o status ($status_prod) do botão (Habilitado? Sim ou Não), e gravar também o endereço ($link_prod) de destino do botão. Mas ele só esta gravando agora a opção SIM, e não estou conseguindo descobrir como fazer com que ele grave a opção selecionada independente de qual.

```
    <?php
    @session_start(); // Inicia a session.

    if(!isset($_SESSION['hab_prod'])){ 
    // Se a Session não existir eu crio...
    $status_prod = 'Sim'; // Carrega esse conteúdo
    $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

    //Armazena os dados na sessão que pode ser bidimensiona(array)
    $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod']=$status_prod;
    $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod']=$link_prod;

    }else if(isset($_SESSION['hab_prod'])){
     // Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
    $status_prod = $_SESSION['hab_prod']["status_prod"];
    $link_prod = $_SESSION['hab_prod']["link_prod"];
    }
    ?>

    <?php
//pega o valor do botao
        if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){ // só entra aqui, se gale_status tiver sido postado
                $link_prod = null;
                $status_prod = 'Não';

// se a pessoa marcar a opção sim:
        if($_POST['status_prod'] == "1") {
                $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
                $status_prod = 'Sim';

        //}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){ // Com essa linha funciona a opção NÃO
        if(!empty($status_prod)) {              // Com essa linha funciona a opção SIM

// Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod']=$status_prod;
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod']=$link_prod;

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
        <script language='javascript'>
        window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
        </script>";
        }}} // Retirar uma Chave se for usar a opção NÃO
    ?>

        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Estou postando os endereços para que os amigos possam verificar o problema que esta ocorrendo.

Endereço do painel onde trocasse o status do botão:
http://www.simuleseusite.com/admin/

Acesso com (Login - usuario) e (Senha - 123)

Entre em (menu/habilitar botão)
Faça o teste trocando de Sim Para Não, e tente destroca-lo, e verá que não esta gravando a opção Sim.

Endereço do Resultado da Habilitação do botão:
http://www.simuleseusite.com/

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajuda para descobrir onde estou errando ficarei muito agradecido.

Brigadão à todos, e grande abraço.

Comment: Testa fazer a verificação com String e não Numero. Ou seja `if($_POST['status_prod'] == "1"` e não somente `== 1`

Comment: Na página sempre volta com o *sim*. Seu input está com o *sim* checked `<input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/>`, mesmo que atualize no BD o HTML sempre vai exibir *sim*.

Comment: Sergio fiz o que vc. sugeriu, mas também não funcionou, ou seja não surtiu efeito a alteração de **== 1** para **== "1"**. E Papa, não estou me referindo aos botões de radio, e sim ao resultado que você terá ao lado esquerdo na pergunta se o "**Link Produtos esta Habilitado?**" ele inicia como **SIM**, você altera para **Não**, mas não consegue voltar para o **Sim** selecionando o botão e atualizando-o. Ai esta  o problema, na atualização quando selecionado o botão **Sim**. Mas valeu pelas dicas, mas continuo no aguardo de dicas para solucionar o problema, e caso eu consiga, posto a solução.

Comment: Fazendo umas pesquisas na rede achei e implantei essa linha **`if(!empty($status_prod)) {`** substituindo essa **`}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){`**, que fez com que funcionasse a opção do **SIM**, porém por algum motivo para de funcionar a opção **NÃO**. E ai alguma ideia de como fazer funcionar a duas opções? Mas temos que retirar uma das tres chaves no fim do código, quando for usar essa opção **`}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){`**. Com essa linha **`}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){`**, funciona a opção Não e com essa **`if(!empty($status_prod)) {`** a opção SIM, e ai?

Comment: Editei o código inserindo a linha que faz com que o **SIM** funcione.

Comment: Onde está o código que esta esse trecho "Link Produtos esta Habilitado?" ?

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado com a ajuda do amigo Miguel, conforme [POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131834/duvida-em-cadastrar-dados-com-bot%C3%B5es-radio/131908#131908)

Abaixo código funcionando:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])) {

if(isset($_POST['status_prod']) && ($_POST['status_prod']) == 0) { // Desabilita o Botão.
    $link_prod = null;
    $status_prod = 'Não';
}else{
    $_POST['status_prod'] == 1; // Habilita o Botão com o Link de destino.
        $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
        $status_prod = 'Sim';
        }
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod'] = $status_prod;
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod'] = $link_prod;

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
        <script language='javascript'>
        window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
        </script>";
        }
?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'/><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Abraços à todos.