# Função empty retorna true (verdade) quando valor é 0

Tags: php

Olá, estou usando o código abaixo para gravar o status ($status_prod) do botão (Habilitado? Sim ou Não), e gravar também o endereço ($link_prod) de destino do botão quando habilitado. Mas ele só esta gravando a opção SIM, e não estou conseguindo descobrir como fazer com que ele grave a opção NÃO quando selecionada.

Reparei que quando insiro esta linha `}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){`, eu consigo gravar o opção NÃO.

E quando troco para esta linha `if(!empty($status_prod)) {`, gravo a opção SIM.

Estou postando os endereços para que os amigos possam verificar o problema que esta ocorrendo.

Endereço do painel onde trocasse o status do botão: http://www.simuleseusite.com/admin/

Acesso com (Login - usuario) e (Senha - 123)

Entre em (menu/habilitar botão) Faça o teste trocando de Sim Para Não, e tente destroca-lo, e verá que não esta gravando a opção Sim.

Endereço do Resultado da Habilitação do botão ou não: http://www.simuleseusite.com/

Segue  código usado abaixo:

```
<?php
//pega o valor do botao
        if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){ // só entra aqui, se gale_status tiver sido postado
                $link_prod = null;
                $status_prod = 'Não';

// se a pessoa marcar a opção sim:
        if($_POST['status_prod'] == "1") {
                $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
                $status_prod = 'Sim';

        //}else if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])){ // Com essa linha funciona a opção NÃO
        if(!empty($status_prod)) {              // Com essa linha funciona a opção SIM

// Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod']=$status_prod;
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod']=$link_prod;

        //header("location:menu_halitar_link.php");

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
        <script language='javascript'>
        window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
        </script>";
        }}} // Retirar uma Chave se for usar a opção NÃO
?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajuda para descobrir onde estou errando ficarei muito agradecido.

Brigadão à todos, e grande abraço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estive a fazer uns testes e a tomar [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220519/in-php-is-0-treated-as-empty) em consideração:

Cheguei à conlusão que o valor inteiro `0` e a string `"0"` são considerados vazios para o método `empty()`, retorna `true`. Neste exemplo em baixo caso escolha "não" (`value="0"`) não vai entrar na primeira condição, enquanto que se escolher o "sim" (`value="1"`) entra nas duas

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['status_prod'])) {
        echo 'Não está vazio: ' .$_POST['status_prod'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])) {
        echo 'Existe: ' .$_POST['status_prod'];
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label>Habilitar o Link</label><br><br>
    <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
    <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'><label>Não</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

Podemos conferir isto se:

```
var_dump(empty(0)); // bool(true)
var_dump(empty("0")); // bool(true)
var_dump(empty(1)); // bool(false)
...
```

Pelo HTML algum valor do botão `radio` vai ser sempre enviado, pois `sim` vai começar sempre checked, você pode contornar isto da seguinte maneira:

```
if(isset($_POST['status_prod']) && $_POST['status_prod'] == 0) {
    // input "Não", $_POST['status_prod'] = 0
}
else {
    // input é sim
    $_POST['status_prod'] = 1; // inserir esta linha por segurança
}
```

PS: Em príncipio vai ser sempre enviado um dos valores, pois o seu "Sim" começa com `checked`, mas temos SEMPRE fazer as verificações do lado servidor

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda do amigo Miguel que me deu uma luz para que conseguisse chegar ao meu objetivo, que é poder gravar o Status do botão e habilita-lo de acordo com a seleção SIM ou NÃO.

Acesse os endereços mencionados acima para efetuar o teste e verificar o resultado.

Abaixo código funcionando perfeito.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['status_prod'])) {

if(isset($_POST['status_prod']) && ($_POST['status_prod']) == 0) { // Desabilita o Botão.
    $link_prod = null;
    $status_prod = 'Não';
}else{
    $_POST['status_prod'] == 1; // Habilita o Botão com o Link de destino.
        $link_prod = '<li><a href="'.$end.'prod_index.php" class="nav1">'.$bot_prod.'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
        $status_prod = 'Sim';
        }
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod'] = $status_prod;
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod'] = $link_prod;

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
        <script language='javascript'>
        window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
        </script>";
        }
?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='0'/><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Agradeço a atenção de todos os amigos ao meu problema, que com o auxilio do amigo Miguel foi solucionado.

Abraços à todos.

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score -3):

O método empty que é um método nativo do PHP, retorna true sempre que um valor de uma variável for vazia, no entanto, é importante sabermos em que situações, no PHP esse método interpretará como vazio. São eles:

- **' '** ,uma string vazia
- **0** ,um inteiro zero
- **0.0** ,flutuante zero
- **null** ,variável nula
- **array()**, um array vazio
- **false**, um booleano falso
- **$valor**, uma variável que não possui ainda uma atribuição.

Em todos esses casos, o empty sempre retornará como true.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).